# How to prepend url with http:// using stringWithFormat in Swift

Tags: string, swift, stringwithformat

I'm building a custom browser using UIWebView.

Use case: User enters "www.abc.com" into the address bar. Error below thrown:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x19860770 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://www.abc.com, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://www.abc.com, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}
```

Reason: the URL needs to be prepended with "http://"

I would like to use the `stringWithFormat` method of NSString, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. In Objective-C, we have;

```
NSString* modifiedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];
```

In Swift, the method is not there?!

```
var modifiedURLString: String = String(`stringWithFormat not here?!...`)
```

I then tried mixing Objective C with Swift:

var modifiedURLString: NSString = [NSString `stringWithFormat not here?!...`

Then I tried straight-up Objective-C:

NSString* modifiedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://", urlString];

Thank you for your help. Sincerely, Keith

Comment: The intended `"http://" + suffix` didn't just work?

Comment: I was using this tutorial. Look under "Correcting User Input"
http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/22/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-3/

Answer (score 65):

The equivalent of NSString's formatWithString: is just "format:", as shown below, but there is no real need to do that for the example you have given. Just append strings, or use interpolation...

```
let urlString = "www.abc.com"
var modifiedURLString = NSString(format:"http://%@", urlString) as String
// or just
modifiedURLString = String(format:"http://%@", urlString)
// or
let simpler = "http://" + urlString
// or use string interplotaion
let simplest = "http://\(urlString)"
```

Answer (score 17):

Just for the sake of being complete here (though of a 4th way), here are your options:

1: Swift way of using NSString's stringWithFormat:

```
let url = NSString(format: "http://%@", aSuffix)
```

2: Take advantage of Swift's ability concatenate strings with the "+" operator.

```
let url = "http://" + aSuffix
```

3: Use NSString's `stringByAppendingString()` method.

```
let url = "http://"
url.stringByAppendingString(aSuffix)
```

4: String interpolation.

```
let url = "http://\(aSuffix)"
```

Comment: You missed a closing bracket on the first way.

Answer (score 8):

You can use string interpolation:

```
let site = "www.abc.com"
let url = "http://\(site)"
```

Comment: Just wondering about this, what os the format comes from the NSLocalizedString? Is there a Swift method to do this?