# Javascript to elegantly prepend a slug with the rest of the URL?

Tags: javascript, html

Could anyone offer an elegant snippet of Javascript that will change URLs like these

```
<a href="joebiden" title="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter">Joe</a>
<a href="berniesanders" title="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter">Bernie</a>
```

To URLs like these:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/joebiden" title="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter">Joe</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/berniesanders" title="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter">Bernie</a>
```

So that the twitter URL is prepended?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prepend url with http:// using stringWithFormat in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247263/how-to-prepend-url-with-http-using-stringwithformat-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet looks for `<a>` elements with an `aria-label` value of "Twitter", and prepends "https://twitter.com/" to the existing `href` value.

```js
for (let a of Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))) {
  if (a.getAttribute('aria-label') === 'Twitter') {
    a.setAttribute('href', 'https://twitter.com/' + a.getAttribute('href'))
  }
}

// Show results
for (let a of Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))) {
    console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<a href="joebiden" title="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter">Joe</a>
<a href="berniesanders" title="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter">Bernie</a>
```

Comment: You are quite the bomb. Thank you. :)

Comment: I did this to make it conditional on the link even being populated: `code`     
for (let a of Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))) {
if (a.getAttribute('aria-label') === 'Twitter') {
if (a.getAttribute("href") !== "") {
a.setAttribute('href', 'https://twitter.com/' + a.getAttribute('href'))
// Show results
for (let a of Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))) {
    console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
}
}
}
}

`code`